# Google Apps Script for Gmail Deletion

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail

I use a simple Script to delete all emails after 1 day if they are labelled 'camera'. This has been working for months.  I haven't changed it but it suddenly stopped working.

The script still has permission to run on my Gmail but has stopped.

Any advice appreciated.

The script is;

```
function cleanUp() {
  var delayDays = 1 // Enter # of days before messages are moved to trash
  var maxDate = new Date();
  maxDate.setDate(maxDate.getDate()-delayDays);
  var label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("camera");
  var threads = label.getThreads();
  for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
    if (threads[i].getLastMessageDate()<maxDate)
      {
        threads[i].moveToTrash();
      }
  }
}
```

Thanks,
Sam

Comment: Does it show any error?

Comment: Hi, no error message is shown. And I have error notifications switched on, but haven't had notification of any error.

Comment: Use the logger to see if the script finds the threads an check also the other variables... Logger.log(value)

Answer (score 0):

Can you log over the loop to check if it's iterating?

Comment: Hi how would I so this please?

Comment: just add 

    if (threads[i].getLastMessageDate()<maxDate)
      {
        threads[i].moveToTrash();
        Logger.log(threads[i]);
      }

Run and check the log, send the result here.

Comment: OK will do when I get to a computer and let you know. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Run this to know if there any messages that need to be processed.  `function getCount() {
  var count=0; var delayDays = 1 
  var maxDate = new Date();
  maxDate.setDate(maxDate.getDate()-delayDays);
  var label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("camera");
  var threads = label.getThreads();
  for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
    if (threads[i].getLastMessageDate()<maxDate)
      {
        count++;
      }
  } Logger.log(count);
}`

Comment: [14-02-17 21:14:16:142 GMT] GmailThread

[14-02-17 21:14:16:351 GMT] GmailThread
   [14-02-17 21:14:18:562 GMT] GmailThread
   [14-02-17 21:14:18:897 GMT] GmailThread
   [14-02-17 21:14:19:241 GMT] GmailThread
   [14-02-17 21:14:19:805 GMT] GmailThread
   [14-02-17 21:14:24:022 GMT] GmailThread
   ....loads of the same...
[14-02-17 21:17:53:986 GMT] GmailThread
[14-02-17 21:17:54:220 GMT] GmailThread

Comment: With you log the script is calling move to Trash successfully. Are you sure that nothing is happening?